Is there a way to circumvent the longer VRF2.5 subscription IDs throwing an error code in Chainlink Bootcamp day 8?
VRF migration to 2.5 has caused subscription IDs to become much, much longer. When trying to finish the final classes of the bootcamp, we're not able to deploy Runners.sol because of this. Error code is:
Error: value out-of-bounds (argument=null, value="105738983793834384342104675306602751844884645096376510750130577637315961236551", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.7.0)

Please advise
I tried to grab a couple more subscriptions, then ran through the list of subs. All showing the longer ID format.

The Runners.sol contract uses VRF 2.0. The current user interface at https://vrf.chain.link/ only allows the creation of V2.5 subscriptions.
To create a V2.0 subscription, call the createSubscription function on the VRF 2.0 Coordinator contract on the network you'll deploy your own contract. The VRF 2.0 Coordinator contract addresses for all supported networks are on the Supported Networks page.
E.g.: Sepolia or Fuji
After the transaction settles, you can find the 2.0 subscription ID at https://vrf.chain.link/. From there, you can fund it and add your consumer contracts.
Enjoy the bootcamp!

What exactly do you mean by "call the createSubscription function on the VRF 2.0 Coordinator contract on the network you'll deploy your own contract"?
Are the steps done in the Remix IDE?

Here's the updated version of a Runners.sol smart contract for Day 8 of the Chainlink Bootcamp that uses the VRF 2.5
https://github.com/solangegueiros/chainlink-bootcamp-2024/blob/main/Runners.sol
